# Oracle Database - Can the installed Java version in the xxx/oracle/product/11.2.x.x/jdk/ be upgraded?

Tags: java, oracle11g

By default when you install the Oracle Database, it installs a JDK/JRE into the directory xxx/oracle/product/11.2.x.x/jdk/.

This appears to be hardcoded into the Oracle Tools such as opatch, dbca etc.    i.e. Java is required to support the database management.

With the latest version of Oracle 11.2.0.4.3 the version of Java that is provided is 1.5.0_51.

Has anyone successfully patched this version of Java to a JDK 6/7/8 recent version?  NB. The PSU updates from Oracle don't appear to patch this.

NB. This question isn't related to the OJVM which runs inside the Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Well, you can, if you're willing to break your database installation and violate your support contract.

See [this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/10665012#10665012):

> The JVM is an integral part of Oracle and without the proper,
> certified version of the JVM the database will not run properly. In
> fact if you use Oracle installer and elect to remove the JVM the
> database itself will be removed also.
>
> Oracle 11g installs with JDK 1.5 and that is the ONLY version that is
> certified to work properly with 11g. If you attempt to use anyother
> version you are violating your support contract and will likely have
> errors.

*NB. This question isn't related to the OJVM which runs inside the Oracle Database.*

And how do you know it's not related?  The "OJVM which runs inside the Oracle database" has to have a JVM installation known to work with the database somewhere.

Comment: Because the OJVM can be upgraded separately.  This doesn't change the version that is deployed in the xxx/oracle/product/11.2.x.x/jdk/ directory to operate the management tools.  

i.e. After upgrading the OJVM to 1.6.0_115,  the JRE installed in xxx/oracle/product/11.2.x.x/jdk/ is still 1.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late.

The embedded JVM cannot be upgraded with any arbitrary JDK/JRE by customers; it requires some development work in terms of security, memory management, and so on,  as part of the RDBMS relase. Iow, only the database develpoment team can do it.
The 12c R1  release of the Oracle database comes with JDK 6 (the default) and JDK 7 (upgrade by running a one liner Perl script).

The RDBMS comes with a JRE for use by Oracle tools exclusively which is orthogonal to the embedded JVM.

Comment: The answer above is helpful technically but could use some spelling / grammar editing.